# Does JS always use two bytes per character to store strings?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management

I'm storing a very large ( >1MB ) bitmask in memory as a string and am curious about how JS stores strings internally.  I have the feeling, based on the fact that

```
String.fromCharCode( 65535 ).charCodeAt( 0 ) === 65535
```

, that all strings are unicode, but I'm not certain.  Basically I'm trying to find out if it would be more efficient, in terms of memory usage, to bitmask against 16-bit characters than 8-bit characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much RAM does each character in ECMAScript/JavaScript string consume?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217015/how-much-ram-does-each-character-in-ecmascript-javascript-string-consume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_internal_string_guide#IDL_String_types

I believe it is very very browser dependent but the Mozilla documentation sheds some light on how they do it internally for JS strings.

The short answer is they use UTF-16

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Answer (score 0):

Check out this discussion.

[JavaScript strings - UTF-16 vs UCS-2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715980/javascript-strings-utf-16-vs-ucs-2)

In short, just because some Javascript engines use a 16 bit encoding does NOT make it UTF16. Edge case surrogate pairs are handled MUCH differently between the two.